# Cant send requests for FastAPI for token creation with username password in Authorization header via postman

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi

I am fairly new to python and fastapi.
I have used the exact code from FastAPI website as below from the website:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/#handle-jwt-tokens

When I use this code and run , it executes and when I use postman and send this request with username and password in the body it works. Although I want to pass username and password via Authorization header and the code throws error saying missing body : username and password.

What do I need to change in the code for it to accept POST requests for token creation when only Authorization header credentials are sent.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Union

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from jose import JWTError, jwt
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing_extensions import Annotated

#to get a string like this run:
#openssl rand -hex 32**
SECRET_KEY = "09d25e094faa6ca2556c818166b7a9563b93f7099f6f0f4caa6cf63b88e8d3e7"
ALGORITHM = "HS256"
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30


fake_users_db = {
    "johndoe": {
        "username": "johndoe",
        "full_name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@example.com",
        "hashed_password": "$2b$12$EixZaYVK1fsbw1ZfbX3OXePaWxn96p36WQoeG6Lruj3vjPGga31lW",
        "disabled": False,
    }
}


class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str


class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: Union[str, None] = None


class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: Union[str, None] = None
    full_name: Union[str, None] = None
    disabled: Union[bool, None] = None


class UserInDB(User):
    hashed_password: str


pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")

app = FastAPI()


def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)


def get_password_hash(password):
    return pwd_context.hash(password)


def get_user(db, username: str):
    if username in db:
        user_dict = db[username]
        return UserInDB(**user_dict)


def authenticate_user(fake_db, username: str, password: str):
    user = get_user(fake_db, username)
    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):
        return False
    return user


def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: Union[timedelta, None] = None):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt


async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(fake_users_db, username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user


async def get_current_active_user(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_user)]
):
    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user


@app.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
    form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()]
):
    user = authenticate_user(fake_users_db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}


@app.get("/users/me/", response_model=User)
async def read_users_me(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_active_user)]
):
    return current_user


@app.get("/users/me/items/")
async def read_own_items(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_active_user)]
):
    return [{"item_id": "Foo", "owner": current_user.username}]
```

I tried passing oauth2_scheme in depends but that failed :

```
@app.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
    form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]
```

and all requests came NOT AUTHENTICATED.

Comment: `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` expects a username/password pair as _form_ variables (as the name indicates). If you don't want to have them as form variables, then using that class is probably the wrong thing to do. You can use `Header()` to manually get a header instead (i.e. `authorization = Annotated[str, Header()]` or something similar).

Comment: @MatsLindh When I added that as below:

`@app.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
    authorization: Annotated[str, Header()]
):
    print("Auth is ", authorization)
    # Extract username and password from the Authorization header
    scheme, credentials = authorization.split()
    username, password = credentials.split(":") `

It prints: 
Auth is  Basic am9obmRvZTpzZWNyZXQxMg==
and error as below: 
username, password = credentials.split(":")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Yes, that is how the basic auth is transferred (its a base64 encoded value). However, if what you want to do is http basic auth, use the pre-made solution: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/